# C# WPF .Net4.8 Framework ReadOnly TextBox Text Binding Delayed Update

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, relaycommand

I have a string "ConnectionStatus" which is bound to a textbox text property

```
    private string connectionStatus;
    public string ConnectionStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return connectionStatus;
        }

        set
        {
            if (connectionStatus != value)
            {
                connectionStatus = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ConnectionStatus");
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a button connected to a RelayCommand:

```
    void ConnectCmd(object parameter)
    {
        ConnectionStatus = "Connecting..";

        // Do some stuff

        ConnectionStatus = "Connected"
    }
```

XML

```
   <TextBox x:Name="TextBlock_ConectedToName" 
               Grid.Column="1"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               Height="40" 
               Margin="5" 
               FontSize="26"
               IsReadOnly="True"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
               VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
               Text="{Binding ConnectionStatus, 
                              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

When the button is pressed, the Relay Command is called, which then
updates the string "ConnectionStaus" to "Connecting...", I then do
some processing, opening a serial port, and change ConnectionStatus to
"Connected" if successful. However, the "Connecting..." text is never
displayed, The text updating only seems to trigger when the
RelayCommand function finishes. How do I get the text to update
immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You're running your code in that relaycommand on the default ui thread.
The UI updates on the UI thread.
It can only do one thing at once.

You could make your relaycommand async and free up the ui thread momentarily. using.

```
await Task.Delay(20);
```

Don't forget to put async in your relaycommand or use an implementation does that for you.